# AngularJS including javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could someone explain why this is working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="appLogin">
<head>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../Global/config.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to add my config.js script like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="appLogin">
<head>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var element1 = document.createElement("script");
        element1.src = "../Global/config.js";
        document.head.appendChild(element1);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I get:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=appLogin&p1=Error%….c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A49723%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A431)
```

appLogin is my angular module defined in config.js. In both cases when I use developer tools in my browser I see that the script is loaded but for some reason the second approach is not working?

Comment: the problem is order, I think in second case, config.js loaded before angular.js

Comment: That's what I thought. But is there any way to load it like I tried in my second example and make it work?

Comment: @Sinan I'm genuinely curious here - what is the advantage of the second method, in general?

Comment: @Steve I don't think there is any, I just tried to load my script dynamically in html, thought it would work like this, I'm just curious what the problem is?

Comment: are you sure you didn't add 'ng-app' in your actual test there? because in the example here there ain't any ng-app... because if there were, that error can occur.

Comment: @NoypiGilas I have ng-app in my html tag. And it's working in my first example but not in the second.

Comment: the problem is when angular tries to bootstrap... the 'config.js' is not yet downloaded. Sometimes the error won't appear with the second example -- because the way it is loaded was async... so, when ng-app tries to ask for the module -- there is a chance that config.js is not yet downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it now.
As all of you mentioned, the problem is that appLogin does not exist yet.
I solved my problem using document.readyState():

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getConfig() {
        var element1 = document.createElement("script");
        element1.src = "../config.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element1);
    }
    if (document.readyState === "complete") { getConfig(); }

</script>
```

Thank you guys. :)

Comment: @NoypiGilas have to wait 2 days because it's my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

the second example tries to download and create the module asynchronously.

so, there is a chance that 'appLogin' does not yet exist when angular tries to bootstrap.

unlike the first example, browsers wait for the script tag to finish. so, the document's ready event is not yet fired.

i can remember, that auto-bootstrap begins when the ready event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getConfig() {
   var element = document.createElement("script");
   element1.src = "../Global/config.js";
   document.body.appendChild(element);
  }
  if (window.addEventListener)
   window.addEventListener("load", getConfig, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent)
   window.attachEvent("onload", getConfig);
  else window.onload = getConfig;
</script>
```